# WPF Button in Datagrid shrink or disappear

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a small problem with my datagrid. I don't want the users to be able to add rows to the datagrid. But when I set `CanUsersAddRows=True` my three `Buttons` in the datagrid shrink for some reason and are not really visible. Is that a bug or am I making a mistake ?

Here is my datagrid code:

```
 <DataGrid
            x:Name="taskGrid"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            Background="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignBackground}"
            Foreground="#FF000000"
            IsReadOnly="False"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Times}"
            CanUserAddRows="True"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTime}"
            VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">

            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn
                    Width="0.25*"
                    Binding="{Binding Mitarbeiter}"
                    Header="Mitarbeiter" />
                <!--StringFormat='HH:mm:ss',-->
                <DataGridTextColumn
                    Width="0.25*"
                    Binding="{Binding startTime,  ConverterCulture={x:Static gl:CultureInfo.CurrentCulture}}"
                    Header="Startzeit" />
                <DataGridTextColumn
                    Width="0.25*"
                    Binding="{Binding endTime,  ConverterCulture={x:Static gl:CultureInfo.CurrentCulture}}"
                    Header="Endzeit" />
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn
                    Width="0.25*"
                    Binding="{Binding Nachgetragen}"
                    Header="Nachgetragen" />
                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button
                                x:Name="btnOpenDetails"
                                Background="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignBackground}"
                                BorderThickness="0"
                                Click="btnOpenDetails_Click"
                                Foreground="#FF000000"
                                Tag="{Binding AuftragID}">
                                Details
                            </Button>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button
                                x:Name="btnChangeTaskNumber"
                                Background="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignBackground}"
                                BorderThickness="0"
                                Click="btnChangeTaskNumber_Click"
                                Foreground="#FF000000"
                                IsEnabled="True"
                                Tag="{Binding ID}">
                                Auftragsnummer ändern
                            </Button>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button
                                x:Name="btnDeleteEntry"
                                Background="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignBackground}"
                                BorderThickness="0"
                                Click="btnDeleteEntry_Click"
                                Foreground="#FF000000"
                                Tag="{Binding AuftragID}">
                                Löschen
                            </Button>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

The following image shows an example when I set the property `CanUsersAddRows=True` in the datagrid control (Note the three buttons on the right hand):

[image]

The next image shows the same stuff, but this time with `CanUsersAddRows=False`:

[image]

As you can see, the buttons kinda disappear. What is going on. What do I need to change?

Thanks!

Comment: Issue is with Background="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignBackground}" make it staticresource

Comment: Didn't change anything for me. I even removed the property and still no changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to kinda fix it. I gave the `<DataGridTemplateColumn>` column a width. That fixed the problem. But I still don't understand why it works when `CanUsersAddRows=False`. A better answer would be appreciated!